# How can I break an infinite loop at runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse

Say that I have:

```
b = true;
while(b){}
```

Is there any way to continue on after this point? Like some way to modify the value of b without stopping and re running the program?

I want to do this as a simple method to pause the program for an unspecified amount of time, that changes all the time.

Comment: You could set a breakpoint. Or prompt from stdin, blocking until you get a new line.

Comment: What triggers this resumption?

Comment: Is this related to Halting problem ?

Comment: Another thread will have to modify the value of `b`. And `b` should probably be `volatile` so changes to the value are visible between threads. Or instead of spinning you could await a `Condition` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

Comment: There are better ways to wait than a busy wait, like using callbacks (a function you give to the function you are waiting on to call when it's done)

Comment: An infinite do-nothing loop is not a good way to "pause" a program: it'll use as much CPU time as it possibly can, up to 100% of a CPU core, doing absolutely nothing.  Use [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-), or [`Object.wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) and [`Object.notify`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your program in debug mode you can inject code that will break the loop. In the example posted just change:

```
b = true;
while(b){}
```

to:

```
b = true;
while(b){b=false;}
```

Then save the file and the loop will be broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the value of `b` from a data source that is modifiable by the user during runtime.

This can be anything from a database, a network socket, or simply a file.

In this case I would recommend a socket. Below is a very rough, but working, example.

Once you start the program in Eclipse, you need to open a terminal window and `telnet localhost 10008`.

The accepted commands via the socket are:

`<numeric value>` = pause the app for that amount of milliseconds

`BYE` = close the socket

`STOP` = completely stop the app

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class RuntimePause extends Thread {
    protected static boolean appRunning = true;
    protected Socket clientSocket;

    private long pause = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        RuntimePause app = new RuntimePause();
        app.start();

        while (true) {
            app.listen();
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        while (appRunning) {

            System.out.println("App running...");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            if (pause > 0) {
                System.out.println("App pausing for " + pause + " ms");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(pause);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                pause = 0;
            }

        }
    }

    public void listen() {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10008);
            System.out.println("Connection Socket Created");
            try {
                while (appRunning) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for Connection");
                    new NetworkSocket(serverSocket.accept());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Accept failed.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10008.");
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Could not close port: 10008.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public class NetworkSocket extends Thread {

        public NetworkSocket(Socket clientSoc) {
            clientSocket = clientSoc;
            start();
        }

        public void run() {
            {
                System.out.println("New Communication Thread Started");

                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                            clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    String inputLine;

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("Received: " + inputLine);

                        // Client sent a pause command
                        try {
                            long pauseCommand = Long.parseLong(inputLine);
                            pause = pauseCommand;
                            out.println("OK, pausing for " + inputLine + " ms");
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            //
                        }

                        // Client wishes to terminate connection to socket
                        if (inputLine.equals("BYE")) {
                            out.println("OK, bye!");
                            break;
                        }

                        // Client orders the app to stop
                        if (inputLine.equals("STOP")) {
                            out.println("OK, stopping!");
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    }

                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Problem with Communication Server");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, this code is not production ready. It simply serves as a example of how you can approach the problem. You want to ensure that the variables are accessed in a thread-safe way.

Comment: Yeah this is the correct answer. I would add that, you most likely wouldn't want to write code that constantly checks a file. Rather you should take a look at Java's libraries for Threading and Processes : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html.

In microarchitecture what you're thinking of is an 'Interrupt' where a cpu's current processes can be interrupted and prioritised based on its IRQ. In Java, I'm not too familiar with what the appropriate library may be unfortunately

Comment: On the code above, please note that the hardcoded `Thread.sleep(1000);` is also a large pause to demonstrate that the app is running. You would normally replace it with actual work, and add a smaller pause (i.e. 100ms) to avoid taking over the cpu time.

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL b;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create a button
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    //Which is black
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //Add it to the view
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    //When you press the button, do stopPrintingB method
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(stopPrintingB) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    b = true;
    /*
     * This is a GCD means not in the main thread
     * If you make while(b) in the main thread
     * the program will not do stopPrintingB method until the main thread is free
     */
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        while (b) {
            NSLog(@"printing b");
        }
    });
}

//make b false and stopPrintingB
- (void)stopPrintingB
{
    b = false;
}
```

Comment: I'm 99% certain that this is objective-c and not applicable to a java question.